# Image of linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have the following question: Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. Is it true that, since $T$ is a continuous mapping, the pre-image of an open set is open, and more over, $T$'s image on a compact set is also compact?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes. automatic continuity follows from the fact the space is finite dimensional.It certainly preserves connectedness and compactness. had other properties of continuous functions as well.